# Manager isn't available auth.User has been swapped

Tags: python, django

As a precursor to asking, I have already looked at a few similar questions and answers.

I am trying to extend my user class to include other fields and then pass down these extra fields as payload on my access_token.

I get this error message when I try to run makemigrations/migrate or run my code

```
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'accounts.CustomerUser'
```

This is what I have in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

    # #extending user model to include
    class CustomerUser(AbstractUser):
        city = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

serializers.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        #removed url from fields
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city', 'country', 'bio']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }
        def create(self,validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                                            username=validated_data['username'],
                                            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                                            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                            city=validated_data['city'],
                                            country=validated_data['country'],
                                            bio=validated_data['bio'],
                                            email=validated_data['email'])
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return user

#customizing the payload we get from our access tokens
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['first_name'] = user.first_name
        token['last_name'] = user.last_name
        token['country'] = user.country
        return token

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in User._meta.fields if field.name not in('id', 'qual_key', 'qual_desc')]
    list_display.insert(0, '__str__')
```

and api.py:

```
class RegisterApi(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request, *args,  **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "message": "User Created Successfully.  Now perform Login to get your token",
        })
```

just to show you the structure of my project here is my urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('api/token/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/register', RegisterApi.as_view()),
]
```

**UPDATE**

Here are my settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomerUser'
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.set_password(serializer.validated_data['new_password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'status': 'password set'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

When you create a custom user model that extends `AbstractUser` and has more fields than the default `User` model, you should create a custom model manager for it. The custom manager should extends `BaseUserManager` and implements `create_user` and `create_superuser` methods, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model).

Then declare custom user manager in `CustomerUser` model

```py
class CustomerUser(AbstractUser):
    ...

    objects = CustomerUserManager()
```